# async:false option not working in $.ajax() , is it depreciated in jQuery 1.8+ for all use cases?

Tags: jquery

I'm confused about using the async: false option with $.ajax(). According to the $.ajax() documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated;
>       you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding 
>       methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

I don't know what jqXHR ($.Deferred) means. Is using async:false for any reason depreciated, or is jqXHR ($.Deferred) some sort of special use case?

I ask as I'm having trouble getting an $.ajax() call to happen asynchronously.This is with jQuery 1.8.2:

```
var ret = {};

$.ajax({
   async:           false,
    method:         'GET',
    contentType:    'application/json',
    dataType:       'jsonp',
    url:            '/couchDBserver',
    error:          myerr,
    success:        function(data) {

        var rows = data.rows;

        //something that takes a long time
        for(var row in rows) {
             ret[rows[row].key] = rows[row].value;
        }

        console.log('tick');
    }
});
console.log('tock');
console.log(JSON.stringify(ret))
```

My console output is:

> tock
>       {}
>       tick

Am I doing something wrong, or am I doing something *wrong*?

Comment: I would put the `tock` code and everything else that is needed to run after the ajax request in the `success` function. Async AJAX is a little sloppy.

Comment: I suppose it's impossible to create synchronised `JSONP` request since it's not an `AJAX` at all. I see you load data from the same origin, any reason to use `JSONP`?

Comment: I understand this, and it's something I've tried to avoid in the past. However, I often end up with spagetti code, which is essentially trying to make synchronous requests. Sometimes you need to make a reqeust, assess the results, and then make another request based on your assessment (ad infinitum). Is there something I don't get about $.ajax() that makes synchronous requests a *bad thing*? Is there a different library I should be using to make 'GET', 'POST' and 'PUT' requests in these situations?

Comment: @Tommi. aha, I'm only using 'jsonp' to test the idea. (i've got a remote server somwhere I use for testing). The actual application makes local 'json' requests. So async: false doesn't work with 'jsonp'?

Comment: Yes, JSONP does not use XHR object.

Comment: also, @Tommi answered my question in the comment above: async requests hang the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You trying to use JSONP techinque with async:false at the same time. This is not possible. JSONP is actually creating a `script` element and appending it somewhere to the document, so it's not an XHR and jQuery can't pass the sync flag anywhere. Since you get data from the same origin, just change dataType to

```
dataType:       'json',
```

However, everyone can tell you that synchronous requests are not good they hang your browser. You should use them only in a small number of cases.

Answer (score 12):

what it is saying is, if your request is `async: false` then you should not use `ajax.done()`, `ajax.fail()` etc methods to register the callback methods, instead you need to pass the callback methods using `success/error/complete` options to the ajax call

correct

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    success: function(){
    },
    error: function(){
    },
    complete: function(){
    }
})
```

wrong

```
$.ajax({
    async: false
}).done(function(){
}).fail(function(){
}).always(function(){
})
```

if async: true //not specified

correct

```
$.ajax({
}).done(function(){
}).fail(function(){
}).always(function(){
})
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    success: function(){
    },
    error: function(){
    },
    complete: function(){
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object in jQuery handles [`promises`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) in AJAX. As it is, `async: false` would completely break the notion of asynchronous calls for which you need to handle promises.

What the jQuery doc snippet is telling you is that something like this would be prohibited.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    /*rest of the options*/
}).done(function(){
    //do something after the response comes back successfully
});
```

However, attaching callback options is completely valid, and is the only way of using AJAX with `async: false`.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    /*Rest of the options*/
    success: function(){
                console.log("foo");
             }
});
```