# jQuery - to wait until function returns and then continue

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I started having some issues with jQuery when I updated to version 1.10.2.

I've been searching for answers, but none of the methods seem to work, I am probably doing something wrong. I would really appreciate some help.

The main problem is that click event does not wait for the result of validateAjax and just says that validateBaan is undefined. I have checked validateAjax function and output gets value of true or false, but I guess by then click event has moved on. I would like the click event to wait for validateAjax result and then continue.

Click event:

```
$('#log-in').on('click', function() {

    // triggers validateAjax
    var validateBaan = validateAjax('fieldId', 'worker');

    // every time I log it says undefined, even though it gets value 
    // (true or false), but too late
    // console.log(validateBaan);

    // this function works
    var validateShift = checkInput({
        shift: {
            field: 'btn-group',
            hasClass: 'active',
            error: 'shifterror'
        }
    });
    // when both are true take some action
    if (validateBaan && validateShift) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Here is validateAjax function:

```
function validateAjax(fieldId, query) {

   var output;

   // field value
   var fieldValue = $('#' + fieldId).val();

   // sending ajax request
   var ajaxQuery = $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "update.php",
     data: 'checkup=checkup&baan=' + fieldValue
    });

   // based on the response, takes action
   ajaxQuery.done(function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
          output = false;
          $('.error-' + fieldId).html(response.error);
       } else if (response.product) {
          $.cookie('tab_name', response.product);
          output = true;
       } else {
          output = true;
       }
       return output;
   });
}
```

I have tried using jQuery when/then, but I did not manage to get it working.

I've never had problems like this with older jQuery versions, so I would appreciate all help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callback function, like

```
$('#log-in').on('click', function() {

    // triggers validateAjax
    // pass anonymus function to be called when ajax is complete
    var validateBaan = validateAjax('fieldId', 'worker', function(){

        // every time I log it says undefined, even though it gets value 
        // (true or false), but too late
        // console.log(validateBaan);

        // this function works
        var validateShift = checkInput({
            shift: {
                field: 'btn-group',
                hasClass: 'active',
                error: 'shifterror'
            }
        });
        // when both are true take some action
        if (validateShift) {
            ...
        }   
    });
});


function validateAjax(fieldId, query, callback) {
    var output;

   // field value
   var fieldValue = $('#' + fieldId).val();

   // sending ajax request
   var ajaxQuery = $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "update.php",
     data: 'checkup=checkup&baan=' + fieldValue
    });

   // based on the response, takes action
   ajaxQuery.done(function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
          output = false;
          $('.error-' + fieldId).html(response.error);
       } else if (response.product) {
          $.cookie('tab_name', response.product);

          //Call you function if condition is trure
          callback();
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Jeei, it worked, thanks a lot. Now I know that I need to use callback to make these things work. Once again, thank you!

Comment: This answer will work, but it not necessary to pass a callback. As the object returned by `$.ajax()` is promise-compatible, it can be returned from `validateAjax()` and, back in the login click handler, responded to with a chained `.done()` with the ex-callback function as its first (and only) parameter. The nett effect is identical but this is the jQuery 1.7+ way of doing things. Myt, please ask if you want the full code, and I will post as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

Is that an ajax, then you can try using **`async: false`**

> Setting **`async to false`** means that the *statement you are calling has to
>   complete before the next statement in your function can be called.*

Since deprecated, the most efficient way is to handle it using **`callback`** functions.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.8 async is deprecated, that's why I am having this trouble.

Comment: ...and the reason it was deprecated is that lengthy synchronous calls in Javascript are a really bad idea. Learn to work with callbacks :)

Comment: @Myt I agree that, then go for callback functions.  On a quick reason I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18268209/1671639

Comment: RIP `async` it was so helpful using it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I should probably do that :D.

Comment: @user1671639 I needed to use callback with validateAjax function like Satpal showed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set async to false:

```
var ajaxQuery = $.ajax({
 async: false,
 type: "GET",
 url: "update.php",
 data: 'checkup=checkup&baan=' + fieldValue
});
```

This will wait until the ajax command is finished before confining with your code.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.8 async is deprecated.

Comment: Do not use synchronous AJAX to solve problems. It is not they way to do things properly (hence being deprecated). Javascript is designed to do most things asynchronously, so learn to work with it :)