# Synchronous call in angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise

I am working on my site project and i am using angular 1.2, i am pretty far but now i have a situation where i need to make synchronous call, but i am not able to find any solution for that, Can any one help me?

Comment: do you mean "asynchronous"? There are plenty of solutions for that, like this: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Comment: Need more information.  A Synchronous HTTP Call?  Or another type of synchronous call?

Comment: Then just wait until your promise is fulfilled before continuing.

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion i don't think we see that request every day. there is no actual value on making the call synchronous, just do as paul said and prevent the user from interacting with the UI using visual tricks loke popup spinners and things like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to make synchronous call inside your code. Then you need to do call your methods inside the success of it,

You're scaring to make synchrous call, That means you haven't maintain your call stack properly.

**Sample Code**

```
    service.whichReturningPromise1.then(
    //success callback
    function(data) {
        service.whichReturningPromise2.then(function() {
            service.whichReturningPromise3.then(function() {

            })
        })
    },
    //error callback
    function(error) {
        //error handling
    });
```

In above example the service call is going after success of each.

**NOTE**

Even jQuery has deprecated `async` option from [**jQuery 1.8**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267969/asyncfalse-option-not-working-in-ajax-is-it-depreciated-in-jquery-1-8-fo)

Thanks.