# Taking data out of the Ajax Jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to taking data out of the Ajax Jsonp.
Why doesn't work this app?
Please Help.

```
var res;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-metrica.yandex.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?end-date=today&ids=ga%3A35416355&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:users&filters=ga:pagePath==/p/etkinlikler.html&start-date=2015-10-25&oauth_token=AQAAAAAVs-uLAASpEAf-MmJK_kHgpU9Fwv8WArM',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) { 
        res = result.totalsForAllResults["ga:users"];
        }
    });
    $("div").html(res);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6vfgemp/

Answer (score 1):

The data is retrieved correctly but since the request is async you cannot set the html outside of the success callback, put it inside the success callback and it will work.

Also it's a good practice to `console.log` the data when you're not sure where the problem is to make sure it is retrieved successfully.

**Edit:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267969/asyncfalse-option-not-working-in-ajax-is-it-depreciated-in-jquery-1-8-fo) is why the `async: false` option is not working, check the accepted answer for the details.

Answer (score 0):

In JSONP you should add a callback parameter to the request. 
The response would be a script calling your callback with the requested data.

So, you should call a URL like this:

```
http://domain.ext/?callback=xxx
```

And you should have a function with name "xxx":

```
function xxx(data) {
    // Here you can manage the received data 
}
```

Also, the requested resource should support JSONP, if it doesn't you will not receive anything in your callback.

Comment: must be out of function :(

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: $("div").html(res); = must be out of function

Comment: Why? You should just put those lines in a function and call that function in callback URL param.

Answer (score 0):

Since the request is asynchronous, your code sets the "div" before the result is actually retrieved. In order to make sure you retrieve the result, and *then* set the div, do this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-metrica.yandex.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?end-date=today&ids=ga%3A35416355&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:users&filters=ga:pagePath==/p/etkinlikler.html&start-date=2015-10-25&oauth_token=AQAAAAAVs-uLAASpEAf-MmJK_kHgpU9Fwv8WArM',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) { 
        res = result.totalsForAllResults["ga:users"];
        $("div").html(res);
        }
    });
```

Comment: $("div").html(res); = must be out of function

Comment: Why would this not work for you:

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-metrica.yandex.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?end-date=today&ids=ga%3A35416355&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:users&filters=ga:pagePath==/p/etkinlikler.html&start-date=2015-10-25&oauth_token=AQAAAAAVs-uLAASpEAf-MmJK_kHgpU9Fwv8WArM&callback=processMe',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: true
    });

  function processMe(data){
 $('div').html(data.totalsForAllResults["ga:users"]);
  }